# Home automation for software enginners using Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'd like to create my own smart home automation. Since I'm software engineer and don't had the opportunity to play with hardware, I think that this is a great time to play with some low-level stuff.

I've read a lot about hardware programming (I do work with C for software programming, in case of need and got basic knowledge in ASM) and I've understand that I should go with Arduino / Rassbery Pi since they're the most easiest hardware to start working with electronics.
I've started to use the Arduino starter kit and do know how to control LEDs etc. but now I'd like to communicate with the room electrics, air condition etc. and looking for some information about how to do that. Theoretically I'll wire a WIFI shield to the Arduino device and will create simple REST API. Then, I'll create an iOS and Android applications for communication with this API.

I'm looking for information in the electricity aspect:
- How can I wire the Arduino to the room light?
- Should I need an Arduino microcontroller for any electric input I'd like to control (and WIFI shield too? it won't make the price too high?)

I'd like to note that in case it's really complicated for a person who don't know much about electricity I don't mind to use any other hardware that can ease the process. My objective is just to be able to program a smart home.

Comment: Are you looking to develop home automation products, or are you looking to build up from ready-to-go blocks to custom-automate your home? I've tinkered with home automation using a product family known as Insteon. It's all safety-certified plug-and-play hardware - including replacement outlets, and switches, and includes a lot of "plug-it-into-an-outlet" components for various other functions, including a USB computer interface, so that any arbitrary software on the computer can monitor/control devices in the system (which communicate over a combination of house wiring and RF).

Comment: I want to be able to control my home using a software I'll program. I do prefer to do the hardware work myself since I'd like to learn the concept. However, if its too risky (electric shocks etc.) for person who don't got hardware experience I don't mind to use a ready-to-go system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions are quite broad, but I'll try to answer you

- *How can I wire the Arduino to the room light?*

You need to use either mosfet components or relays. The most easy one to use is the relay. Usually, you drive the relay with a simple BC337 NPN transistor. What does all that mean? It's all explained on that [page](http://www.susa.net/wordpress/2012/06/raspberry-pi-relay-using-gpio/).

But be careful, playing with electricity can be *really* dangerous.

If you want to make a light gradator, then things will become a bit more complicated, involving digitally controlled triacs, or digitally controlled potentiometer (for low current).

- *Should I need an Arduino microcontroller for any electric input I'd like to control (and WIFI shield too? it won't make the price too high?)*

It depends, there's no absolute answer for that. You can wire your arduinos (or even use ATTiny, which are way cheaper) to each of your switches, or you can have one microcontroller per set of switch etc.. That's up to you to look at how your switches are organized in your place, and how you can design your system to better fit your needs.

The best option, imho, is taking control of "state switches" (you know the switches where when you push once, it's on, and twice it's off). On those you can control all your lights from your electric board, depending on the maker of your device, they can be controlled by 5V, 12V or 20V impulses. So one device on the electric board and you're all set. But those switches need a redesign of the light's circuit in your home...